# Compare two file_csv using pandas DataFrame to find the difference and join F2 into F1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I need help to resolve this problem. If anyone has an idea to create a script using panda DataFrame with python3:

I have two CSV dataset files too long to fit into panda DataFrame display. They have the following structure:

```
F1: 
   gene disease
0  g1   d1
1  g1   d2
2  g1   d3
3  g2   d2
4  g2   d3
5  g2   d4
6  g3   d2
7  g3   d4
8  g4   d1
9  g4   d3

F2:
  gene  phenotype
0  g1   ph1
1  g1   ph2
2  g2   ph2
3  g2   ph3
4  g2   ph4
5  g3   ph4
6  g4   ph1
7  g4   ph3
8  g5   ph4
9  g6   ph2
```

g= gene_name(strig, interger, Float), d = disease_name(string) ph= phenotype

The main goal is to compare all the genes in F2 with the genes in F1, and if they equal, append the name of gene and the phenotype associated to the disease in order to get an output file F3 containing all the diseases associated to phenotype by genes.

This is the expected output:

```
gene disease phenotype
g1   d1      ph2
g1   d2      ph2
g2   d2      ph1
g2   d3      ph2
ect.
```

Can anybody help me create the script? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Where is `ph1` in `g1` in your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a 1 to many relationship between the gene and phenotype and a one to many relationship between the gene and disease. If you join on gene, there will be a many to many. See Example output. Is this what you are looking for?

```
data = [
    ["g1", "d1"], 
    ["g1", "d2"],
    ["g1", "d3"],
    ["g2", "d2"], 
    ["g2", "d3"]
]
f1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns={"gene", "disease"})


data = [
    ["g1", "ph1"], 
    ["g1", "ph2"],
    ["g2", "ph2"], 
    ["g2", "ph3"]
]
f2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns={"gene", "phenotype"})

f1.merge(f2)



idx gene disease phenotype
0   g1  d1  ph1
1   g1  d1  ph2
2   g1  d2  ph1
3   g1  d2  ph2
4   g1  d3  ph1
5   g1  d3  ph2
6   g2  d2  ph2
7   g2  d2  ph3
8   g2  d3  ph2
9   g2  d3  ph3
```

Comment: For learning purposes, I'm trying to write the pseudo algorithm for the merging above between phenotype and diseases. any help appreciated.